# RecyclerView после notifyDataSetChanged изображения накладываются

Tags: android-fragment, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Во фрагменте использую RecyclerView.
После добавления данных в БД произвожу повторное чтение данных, помещаю их в адаптер и вызываю notifyDataSetChanged у адаптера.
После этого изображения накладываются, как будто новые данные в другом слое нарисовались, а старые никуда не делись. И при прокрутке списка старые двигаются, а новые нет.

Адаптер:

```
public class PhotoItemAdapterNoCursor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoItemAdapterNoCursor.PIViewHolder> {

    private static final int LAYOUT_ITEM = R.layout.include_photo_item;

    private int idLayout;
    private Context context;
    private PhotoItem[] list;
    private View root;

    public PhotoItemAdapterNoCursor(Context context, PhotoItem[] list){
        this.context = context;
        this.idLayout = LAYOUT_ITEM;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void setData(PhotoItem[] list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public PhotoItemAdapterNoCursor.PIViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Создаем HOLDER
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(idLayout, parent, false);
        return new PhotoItemAdapterNoCursor.PIViewHolder(rowView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoItemAdapterNoCursor.PIViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Читаем данные из списка
        PhotoItem photoItem = list[position];
        //Заполняем
        //1. Фото
        File image = new File(DB.directory(context), photoItem.getUrl());
        if (image.exists()) {
            Bitmap bmp = MyTool.decodeBitmap(image.getAbsolutePath(), 240, 240);
            holder.ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        //2. Значение и дату
        holder.tvValue.setText(photoItem.getValue().toString());
        holder.tvTarif.setText(photoItem.getTitle());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list != null)
            return list.length;
        else return 0;
    }
    public class PIViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //
        ImageView ivPhoto;
        TextView tvTarif;
        TextView tvValue;
        public PIViewHolder(View item){
            super(item);
            ivPhoto = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.ivPhotoItem_Image);
            tvTarif = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvPhotoItem_Tarif);
            tvValue = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvPhotoItem_Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Фрагмент

```
public class PhotoListFragment extends Fragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    private static final String TAG = "My(PhotoFragment)";
    public static final int FRAGMENT_LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_photos;
    private static final int PHOTO_ITEM_LOADER_ID = 3001;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_CAPTURE = 3003;
    private static final String KEY_METER_ID = "meter_id";
    private static final String KEY_VID_ID = "vid_id";

    private DB db;
    private long meterId;
    private File tempFileImage;

    private RecyclerView rvVids;
    //Корневой view
    View root;
    PhotoItemAdapterNoCursor adapterNoCursor;


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: ");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            //проверяем какой Intent вернул результат
            case PhotoListFragment.REQUEST_CAMERA_CAPTURE:
                //Захват изображения и вызов диалога
                Bundle args = null;
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//                    если положительный результат
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Результат работы камеры");
                    if (tempFileImage.exists()) {
                        //формируем данные
                        args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString(PhotoDialogFragment.KEY_IMAGE_PATH,
                                tempFileImage.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Файла НЕТ!!!!!");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Отмена работы с камерой - нет фото!!");
                }
                showDialogCreateOrEditPhoto(args, PhotoDialogFragment.REQUEST_ADD_PHOTO_DIALOG);
                break;
            case PhotoDialogFragment.REQUEST_ADD_PHOTO_DIALOG:
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Результат Создания фото");
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    //у нас есть фото в кэше и параметры записи
                    //1. фото
                    Bundle result = data.getExtras();
                    String photo = result.getString(PhotoItem.URL);
                    //2. Создание записи
                    long typeId = result.getLong(PhotoItem.TYPE_ID);
                    String ps = result.getString(PhotoItem.PS, "");
                    Integer value = result.getInt(PhotoItem.VALUE, 0);
                    //Заносим запись
                    long id = db.insertPhoto(meterId, typeId, photo, ps, value);
                    if (id >0 ) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Фотография сохранена!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Читаем новые данные в адаптер
        adapterNoCursor.setData(db.loadPhotoItemList(meterId, 1));

                        adapterNoCursor.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ошибка!! Данные не сохранены!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Обновление фрагмента

                }
                break;
            case PhotoDialogFragment.REQUEST_EDIT_PHOTO_DIALOG:
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: Результат Изменения фото");
                break;
        }
    }

    //    Вызов диалога - создать/изменить счетчик
    private void showDialogCreateOrEditPhoto(Bundle args, int requesCode){
        Log.d(TAG, "вызов диалога Создать / изменить фото: ");
        PhotoDialogFragment photoDialog = new PhotoDialogFragment();
        photoDialog.setArguments(args);
        photoDialog.setTargetFragment(this, requesCode);
        photoDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), PhotoDialogFragment.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------onCreateView: ");
        //тут мы задаем свой LAYOUT фрагмента
        root = inflater.inflate(FRAGMENT_LAYOUT, null);
        //Кнопка добавить
        ((Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_photo)).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Добавить показание: ");
                        //Сделать фото
                        //имя файла, временного
                        tempFileImage = db.generateTempNameFile();
                        MyTool.startCameraCapture(PhotoListFragment.this,
                                tempFileImage, PhotoListFragment.REQUEST_CAMERA_CAPTURE);
                        //В методе onActivityResult - запуск диалога
                    }
                }
        );
        Bundle input = getArguments();
        meterId = input.getLong(Meters._ID, 0);

        db = new DB(getActivity());
        if (!db.isOpened())
            db.open();

        //делаем RecyclerView
        rvVids = (RecyclerView)root.findViewById(R.id.rvPhotosLevelUp);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        rvVids.setHasFixedSize(false);
        rvVids.setLayoutManager(lm);

        //Создаем адаптер - NoCursor
        adapterNoCursor = new PhotoItemAdapterNoCursor(getActivity(),
                db.loadPhotoItemList(meterId, 1));
        rvVids.setAdapter(adapterNoCursor);

        return root;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в Activity. Вы после добавления данных снова вызываете создание Fragmentа, и создаете его с методом add, используйте метод replace при отображение фрагмента... Если не получилось добавьте код Activity где создаете этот фрагмент

Comment: Да, похоже во фрагменте дело: В методе Activity - onStart вызываю: PhotoListViewFragment frag = new PhotoListViewFragment();
        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.add(FRAGMENT_ID, frag);
        trans.commit();

Comment: А как определить add использовать или replace?

Comment: Когда вам нужен новый fragment и старый тоже осталься, тогда нужно использовать add, а если просто заменить или обновить то replace... при использовании add старый фрагмент остается на месте...